# ASP.net AccessDataSource Date Inserts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to insert a row with a DATE value. How do I set its default value to `Now()` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to set the default value of a AccessDataSource parameter to something variable is in the code-behind:

```
myAccessDataSource.InsertParameters("date").DefaultValue = DateTime.Now
```